# How to handle unresponsive ex-supervisor on the submission of an article?

Tags: advisor, ethics, paper-submission, interpersonal-issues, communication

During my master's, I had done a project which yielded some interesting results that I and my supervisor started to write up. I moved to a different university (and country) for my PhD and kept contact with the professor. He suggested some edits and I did them. But of late, he is neither replying to my emails nor proceeding with the article, although he promised that we should be able to submit the article quite soon.

I would completely understand if he doesn't want to go forward with the article, but I am confused. I even suggested indirectly that we not go forward and just put it on Arxiv.

Comment: What kind of input do you still need from him? Would it be an option to announce a particular date on which you plan to submit the article, and ask him to send any additional feedback until then?

Comment: As per our last communication, it seemed like we were almost done with the article and just the text needed some more polishing. I asked him in a subsequent mail about a possible timeline for the submission. To which he didn't reply. I have already asked him for an update about the article so many times that I am embarrassed to ask again.